# Setting up a Bone Constraint

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, bone.constraints

I'm thinking about how to use a constraint so that these 3 bones will move outwards or inwards (while staying the same size) when I expand/contract the circle. any ideas on how to set this up? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parent some empties to the curve vertices (select the empty, shift select the curve, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*), create your bones and give a *Child Of* constraint to each of them with the empties as targets:

[image]

Result:

[image]